# Tool to create generative / procedural abstract art for website backgrounds

Tags: website-design, background, procedural-art

I need an abstract, unobtrusive background for a website, something similar to

[image] or [image]

**Is there a tool that can procedurally generate such images with great variation?**

**It should have many parameters that can be adjusted or randomized, like base forms, size, variation, density, color properties, and so on.**

It can be an online tool, desktop software, or plugin. It can be free or commercial.

---

Until now I only found tools that are limited to a very specific kind of image like [BgGenerator.com](https://bggenerator.com/)

[image: BgGenerator.com]

Also, "AI tools" like [photoroom.com/backgrounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL2wc.jpg) (that uses the "Stable Diffusion" algorithm) are not what I'm looking for: They modify and combine images that they obviously copy from the web, and the results are **unpredictable**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about an AI tool? There are lots around now days you can use tools like [midjourney](https://www.midjourney.com/home/) for this. Here is an example made with a few different text prompts:

[image]

**Image 1**: Generated with midjourney *Attribution-NonCommercial license*

Comment: The problem with these AI tools is that the results cannot **predictably** be influenced. I'm looking for a tool where I can experiemen a bit to get some promising starting point, and then **improved it step by step** (and that not only in a way Photoshop can do of course)

Comment: @jaken offcourse you can do that that exactly how they work. You can paint on top of it tell it to make changes here and there and change elements. Just see YouTube on using tools like stable diffusion etc I just used mid journey because it doesn't require a big download.

Comment: ok, maybe I need to learn more about that